# Does the vanguard's Entropy Shield stack with a real physical shield?

Tags: stacking, shield, starfinder

Can a Vanguard have both an Entropy Shield and a real physical shield, and do they stack if so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, they don't stack.

From the [description of the Entropy Shield ability](http://aonsrd.com/Disciplines.aspx?ID=5):

> The shield has no bulk, but it otherwise functions in all regards as a physical shield of the selected type.

From the [rules for shields](http://aonsrd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=717):

> Shield bonuses do not stack with one another, and they do not stack with bonuses gained from cover.

Entropy Shield works just like a physical shield, meaning it provides a Shield bonus to AC.  Shield bonuses don't stack, per the rule quoted above.